# GitHub offline-editor-js examples aren't working anymore, how to fix manually?

Tags: javascript, dojo, esri

I want to use this Library:

https://github.com/Esri/offline-editor-js

Using the samples everything works fine except:

http://esri.github.io/offline-editor-js/samples/appcache-features.html

which throws a 404 Error on:
http://esri.github.io/offline-editor-js/samples/jsolib/nls/dojo_ROOT.js

Can I fix this myself somehow by adding the missing library manually or smth.? I already downloaded everything and can run it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the dojo.js file is somehow broke. Used the default.